# Why does Dominika use her real name to sign up for pool?

Tags: plot-explanation, red-sparrow

In the movie Red Sparrow, Dominika Egorova (Jennifer Lawrence) is strictly told during her training to never reveal her real name. Still when she is assigned to her first mission, she reveals her real name by using it to sign up for the pool.

It can be seen as a gesture to win Nathaniel Nash's (Joel Edgerton) trust. But wasn't it a dumb move to begin with? What if Americans decided to eliminate her after she served her purpose? Or threaten her to continue to work as their mole?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole point of the movie is that Dominika is trying to either escape the life of a Sparrow or, at the very least, take advantage of the information she can gather to protect her mother and improve her life.

Dominika is, as you say, breaking the first rule *deliberately* so as to make contact with Nash and let him know *who she is* and her relationship to a high-ranking SVR member.

It's not without risks but, from my reading, intelligence agents aren't "eliminated" by rival agents as a matter of course. The risk / reward ratio is not worth it.

As for threatening her...with what? She's in constant danger of being eliminated *by her own side*...she doesn't have a lot to lose on that side.

---

In fact this is something constructed for the movie, presumably for plot/timing reasons since, in the original novel, Dominika uses her original name throughout.

Comment: Threaten to disclose her identity as a mole to Russians. I mean using real name will likely to cause more trouble than benefit.

Comment: I think, that was also her trump card to win trust. I mean which trained spy uses her real id while in a mission ?